# Python How to convert 8-bit ASCII string to 16-Bit Unicode

Tags: python, unicode

Although Python 3.x solved the problem that uppercase and lowercase for some locales (for example tr_TR.utf8) Python 2.x branch lacks this. Several workaround for this issuse like https://github.com/emre/unicode_tr/ but did not like this kind of a solution.

So I am implementing a new upper/lower/capitalize/title methods for monkey-patching unicode class with 
[string.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) method.

The problem with maketrans is the lenghts of two strings must have same lenght.
The nearest solution came to my mind is "How can I convert 1 Byte char to 2 bytes?"

---

**Note:** `translate` method does work only ascii encoding, when I pass `u'İ'` (1 byte length \u0130) as arguments to `translate` gives ascii encoding error.

```
from string import maketrans

import unicodedata
c1 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',u'i').encode('utf-8')
c2 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',u'İ').encode('utf-8')
c1,len(c1)
('\xc4\xb1', 2)

# c2,len(c2)
# ('I', 1)
'istanbul'.translate( maketrans(c1,c2))
ValueError: maketrans arguments must have same length
```

Comment: `string.maketrans()` is byte-oriented, so I don't think what you want to do would work, even if you can find some way to convert 8-bit ASCII characters to 16-bit Unicode.

Comment: You mentioned also what I mean and want, 8-bit ASCII to 16-bit Unicode conversion.

Comment: @guneysus: the literal answer to the question in the title in Python is: `unicode_text = ascii_bytestring.decode('ascii')`. "16-Bit Unicode" is very poor terminology: does it mean UCS-2 (unicode string in "narrow" CPython 2 build), or text encoded using UTF-16 encoding, or a Unicode codepoint from BMP, or "16-bit" should be ignored and Python Unicode string should be assumed (as I did)?

Comment: You are right. Because I did not know very well Unicode. I just know that some unicode characters in Turkish alphabet are represented by two characters. The main problem was this. This always confuses my mind. Because of this, I just tried to explain my problem with a poor terminology, because of unfamiliar to terminology and lack of deep technical details of Unicode (or Utf-8 or UTF-16). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode objects allow multicharacter translation via a dictionary instead of two byte strings mapped through `maketrans`.

```
#!python2
#coding:utf8
D = {ord(u'i'):u'İ'}
print u'istanbul'.translate(D)
```

Output:

```
İstanbul
```

If you start with an ASCII byte string and want the result in UTF-8, simply decode/encode around the translation:

```
#!python2
#coding:utf8
D = {ord(u'i'):u'İ'}
s = 'istanbul'.decode('ascii')
t = s.translate(D)
s = t.encode('utf8')
print repr(s)
```

Output:

```
'\xc4\xb0stanbul'
```

The following technique can do the job of `maketrans`.  Note that the dictionary keys must be Unicode ordinals, but the value can be Unicode ordinals, Unicode strings or `None`.  If `None`, the character is deleted when translated.

```
#!python2
#coding:utf8
def maketrans(a,b):
    return dict(zip(map(ord,a),b))
D = maketrans(u'àáâãäå',u'ÀÁÂÃÄÅ')
print u'àbácâdãeäfåg'.translate(D)
```

Output:

```
ÀbÁcÂdÃeÄfÅg
```

Reference: [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate)